# One column dosen't updated in UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$get_season_end_time = $db->query("SELECT `end_times` FROM `seasons` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_assoc();
if (time() > $get_season_end_time['end_times']) {
    $db->query("UPDATE `seasons` SET active='-1', ended='1' ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1");
}
```

For some reason, the `ended` column is updating, but the `active` dosen't.

Any suggestions? thx!

Comment: Why do you have an ORDER BY in your update statement?

Comment: you can't use `ORDER BY` in the update query!

Comment: Actually it's the first time I use it based on an answer in stackoverflow.. Anyway it's dosen't work either way. I tried adding `WHERE ID='6'` instead

Comment: @YazanWYusuf . . . You *can* use `ORDER BY` in an `UPDATE` query:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html.

Comment: What data type is "active" column?

Comment: It's `int`, I tried to change it to `DECIMAL` and it still wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Try to set type of column active to **DECIMAL**

> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value
>   with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the
>   salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it, but I had a bug updating the `active` column to `1` at the end of the script.
I didn't try manualy change the value of the `active` column.

Really sorry for the truble!